# QGIS Clustering based on density

Tags: qgis, clustering, optimization

I have areas of corn I'd like to cluster together based on the amount of area each corn field has. I have centroids calculated for each field, about 71,845 fields, and I'd like to create 13 clusters of centroids that optimally choose an appropriate amount of corn fields that maximizes corn field area. I'd like for non-optimal corn fields to be thrown away. I am using QGIS.

Comment: Hi Jeremy P., welcome! Please, [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/354550/edit) your question post to include a better description of this intention: _" I'd like to create 13 clusters of centroids that optimally choose an appropriate amount of corn fields that maximizes corn field area."_ Can you include examples of the clustering logic rules?

Comment: It also is unclear, whether you want to do spatial clustering, or based on the field size.